# I got CORS error -- cors() is not working

Tags: node.js, axios, cors

After login in server.js, if successful, the React component is shown. I want to receive user information from React component.

The server uses port 5000, and the client is 3000. The client-side component receives information as follows.

```js
const Main = () => {

  async function makeGetRequest() {
    let res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/auth/google/callback');

    let data = res.data;
    console.log(data, 'data');
  }
  makeGetRequest();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Main Page</h2>
        Main Page
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

I know that express has cors and tried using it in `server.js`, but it doesn't work.

I've tried using separate cors and cors options, but it doesn't work.

```js
// server.js

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:5000',
  credentials: true,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_CODE,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
  })
);

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);
app.use('/main', mainRouter);

...
```

I got these errors:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cors [origin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options) should use port 3000, because that’s the domain you want to allow requests from.

Also you don’t need to set the cors headers manually, cors() handles that for you.